# Bootstrap 4 row wrapping with col- class in Safari for Windows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, safari

My HTML:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-4">Column 1</div>
         <div class="col-4">Column 2</div>
         <div class="col-4">Column 3</div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

In Safari for Windows the above code automatically wraps the three columns into 1 column. I have tried using:

```
<style type="text/css" >
    .row:before, .row:after {display: none !important;}
</style>
```

but that doesn't help.

I found the following solutions:

```
.rowSafari{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
 }
```

This works but does not seem very graceful.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what do you mean by "not very graceful"?

Comment: First off, I hope I didn't offend the original author of the solutions. I was just hoping that there was a solution that didn't involve adding a new class to a standard BS class like row.